# Processing Checkbox Group into String

Tags: javascript, html, dom, checkbox

I have a form which contains a series of checkboxes, in a group. Here is the HTML -

```
<input type="checkbox" name="p_contents[]" value="Value 1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="p_contents[]" value="Value 2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="p_contents[]" value="Value 3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="p_contents[]" value="Value 4" />
<input type="checkbox" name="p_contents[]" value="Value 5" />
```

And I wish to process this with javascript -

```
var contents;
for(var i=0; i < document.forms['addForm'].elements['p_contents[]'].length; i++){   
    if(i != (document.forms['addForm'].elements['p_contents[]'].length - 1)){
        if(document.forms['addForm'].elements['p_contents[]'].checked){
            contents += encodeURIComponent(document.forms['addForm'].elements['p_contents[]'][i].value) + ",";
        }
    }else{
        if(document.forms['addForm'].elements['p_contents[]'][i].checked){
            contents += encodeURIComponent(document.forms['addForm'].elements['p_contents[]'][i].value);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure the problem is with the enumeration:

```
document.forms['addForm'].elements['p_contents[]'][i].checked
```

Is this the correct way to process a grouped checkbox form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
var vals = [], p_contents =  document.forms['addForm']['p_contents[]'];
for(var i=0,elm;elm = p_contents[i];i++) {
    if(elm.checked) {
        vals.push(elm.value);
    }
}
```

and if you need the result to be a string just do

```
vals.join(',');
```

If the `encodeURIComponent` is needed, do that before pushing the value into the vals array like this:

```
vals.push(encodeURIComponent(elm.value));
```

So to recap - if you are looking for the exact same result your own code is giving, do this:

```
var contents, vals = [], p_contents =  document.forms['addForm']['p_contents[]'];
for(var i=0,elm;elm = p_contents[i];i++) {
    if(elm.checked) {
        vals.push(encodeURIComponent(elm.value));
    }
}
contents = vals.join(',');
```

You can see it in effect here: http://jsfiddle.net/3MRc7/

Comment: I copy/pasted this code and added an alert(contents); after it - the alert didn't fire :s

Comment: Sorry there was a copy/paste error, try taking the code again and use it, now it should work

Comment: Thanks mate, it works great! This does seem to be a more dynamic solution than adding a unique ID to each. You have saved my life :)

Answer (score 0):

You have several checkboxes with the same name. You can't easily access them by name. Add a unique id to each and use `document.getElementById()`. Note that [`form.elements[]` is indexed by integer, not name, and scans through every element on a form](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_form_elements.asp).

Also, if you assign a long repeating expression to a short-named `var` and then use that short name, it significantly improves readability of your code.

Comment: There is no need to add unique id to each checkboxes in the example you provided.

Answer (score 0):

As specified by @9000 you can do the same by adding elements id and iterating it following way

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) { //you can calculate length as you did before or any alternate way
    var prefix = 'yourPrefixToId';
    if (document.getElementById(prefix + i).checked) {
    // do stuff
    }
}
```